# AFNetworking Get full http response

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, afnetworking

I am querying my server using `AFNetworking`, the latest - to date - version.

My server side PHP is sending a PHP related error but I am unable to see what the error is ( so I can debug it) as  AFNetworking is expecting a JSON.

Could anyone tell me how could I see the full HTTP result. I've researched and I know is something to do with `operation.responseString` inside the `success` / `fail` block  my current block does not have `AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation` and I can't add it as another block variable somehow.

I would really appreciate some help.

The following code uses

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:URL];
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc]initWithBaseURL:url];


    NSURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:URLPATH parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
                             {
                                 //...
                                 }

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                                        success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON){
                                                                                            NSLog(@"Inside the success block %@",JSON);
                                                                                            [[self delegate ]shareExerciseDone:JSON];
                                                                                            [[self delegate] activityIndicatorFinish];

                                                                                        }
                                                                                        failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON){

                                                                                            NSLog(@"Response text is: %@", operation.responseString);
                                                                                            NSLog(@"json text is: %@", JSON);
                                                                                            NSLog(@"Request failed with error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);

                                                                                            [[self delegate] activityIndicatorFinish];
                                                                                        }];

    [operation start];
```

**The error**

```
Request failed with error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0xc1b4520 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}, {
    NSDebugDescription = "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.";
```

Comment: Are you looking for `response.statusCode` or `response.allHeaderFields`? [NSHTTPURLResponse documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPURLResponse_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: No, I need the full HTML text that is outputted by PHP.  i want to see where it fails and what is sending that is not a JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `AFJSONRequestOperation`, just use `AFHTTPRequestOperation`.

Comment: Yes, this or use a proxy like Charles web debugging proxy.

Answer (score 1):

For Uploading Images From iOS to Server i am using Afnetworking

can you try with this Code.and you will get response in success or failure.

```
NSData *userImgToUpload = UIImagePNGRepresentation(userImg.image);
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.domainname.com"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

NSLog(@"%@",@"Uploading data");
NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:usernameTxt.text,@"username", firstnameTxt.text,@"first_name",lastnameTxt.text,@"last_name", nil]; 

//        Upload Image
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/addPatient" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:userImgToUpload name:@"patientimage" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",usernameTxt.text] mimeType:@"image/png"];
    }];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"response: %@",[operation.responseString objectFromJSONString]);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Upload Failed");
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [operation error]);
    }];
    [operation start];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should listen for the `AFNetworkingOperationDidStartNotification` and `AFNetworkingOperationDidFinishNotification` events that fire at the beginning and end of the operation:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(YourOperationStartMethod:) 
                                             name:AFNetworkingOperationDidStartNotification 
                                           object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(YourOperationFinishMethod:) 
                                             name:AFNetworkingOperationDidFinishNotification 
                                           object:nil];
```

You can grab the operation object from the notification like this:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = 
        (AFHTTPRequestOperation *) [notification object];
```

This `operation` object contains `request` and `response` properties.

A good example of how all this works can be found in the [AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger) plugin (which, of course, you could simply use, instead of writing your own thing).